# How to add rows under multi-layered column headers added by StackedHeaderDecorator

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am working on C#. I use this code copied from the link below to show multi-layered column headers to `DataGridView`.

[DataGridView – Stacked Header](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474418/DataGridViewplus-e-plusStackedplusHeader)

I succeeded to show multi-layered col header itself, but I can't add rows under the column headers. Instead, I got the added rows to be appeared in the col headers that are automatically created besides the multi-layered column headers.

[image]

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = dataGridView_syukei;
    StackedHeaderDecorator objREnderer = new StackedHeaderDecorator(dgv);

    dgv.Columns.Add("Name", "a.Name");
    dgv.Columns.Add("1", "a.Id");

    List<TestClass> testClasses = new List<TestClass>();
    TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass();
    testClass1.Id = 1;
    testClass1.Name = "John";
    TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass();
    testClass2.Id = 2;
    testClass2.Name = "Mike";
    testClasses.Add(testClass1);
    testClasses.Add(testClass2);

    dgv.DataSource = testClasses;
}

class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is this winforms? If not, what UI framework are you using?

Comment: Yes, It is windforms.

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. You want the user to be able to add new rows to the grid? ... _"Instead, I got the added rows to be appeared in the col headers that are automatically created besides the multi-layered column headers."_ ... ?

Comment: If you have existing Columns, then set their `DataPropertyName` to match a Property/Column of the datasource. Otherwise, the Control will create new Columns (with `AutoGenerateColumns = true`).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. Your advice solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `AutoGenerateColumns = false` and `DataPropertyName` soloved this problem.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = dataGridView_syukei;
        dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        StackedHeaderDecorator objREnderer = new StackedHeaderDecorator(dgv);

        DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn_Name = new DataGridViewColumn();
        dataGridViewColumn_Name.HeaderText = "a.Name";
        dataGridViewColumn_Name.DataPropertyName = "Name";
        dataGridViewColumn_Name.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        dgv.Columns.Add(dataGridViewColumn_Name);

        DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn_Id = new DataGridViewColumn();
        dataGridViewColumn_Id.HeaderText = "a.Id";
        dataGridViewColumn_Id.DataPropertyName = "Id";
        dataGridViewColumn_Id.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        dgv.Columns.Add(dataGridViewColumn_Id);

        List<TestClass> testClasses = new List<TestClass>();
        TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass();
        testClass1.Id = 1;
        testClass1.Name = "John";
        TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass();
        testClass2.Id = 2;
        testClass2.Name = "Mike";
        testClasses.Add(testClass1);
        testClasses.Add(testClass2);

        dgv.DataSource = testClasses;
    }
```

[image]